# Get first and last Index of a Pandas DataFrame subset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I do got some data within a pandas DataFrame looking like this.

```
df =
        A       B
time                               
0.1     10.0    1
0.15    12.1    2
0.19    4.0     2
0.21    5.0     2
0.22    6.0     2
0.25    7.0     1
0.3     8.1     1
0.4     9.45    2
0.5     3.0     1
```

Based on the following condition I look for a generic solution to find the first and last index of every subset.

```
cond = df.B == 2
```

So far I tried using the groupby concept but without the expected result.

```
df_1 = cond.reset_index()
df_2 = df_1.groupby(df_1['B']).agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
```

This is the output I got.

```
      B       time          
              first    last
0    False    0.1      0.5
1    True     0.15     0.4
```

This is the output I like to get.

```
      B       time          
              first    last
0    False    0.1      0.1
1    True     0.15     0.22
2    False    0.25     0.3
3    True     0.4      0.4
3    False    0.5      0.5
```

How can I accomplish this by a more or less generic approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper `Series` by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for groups by consecutive values, then for aggregation is used dictionary:

```
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()
df_1.B = df_1.B == 2
g = df_1.B.ne(df_1.B.shift()).cumsum()
df_2 = df_1.groupby(g).agg({'B':'first','time': ['first','last']}).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df_2)
       B  time      
   first first  last
0  False  0.10  0.10
1   True  0.15  0.22
2  False  0.25  0.30
3   True  0.40  0.40
4  False  0.50  0.50
```

If want avoid `MultiIndex` use named aggregations:

```
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()
df_1.B = df_1.B == 2
g = df_1.B.ne(df_1.B.shift()).cumsum()
df_2 = df_1.groupby(g).agg(B=('B','first'),
                           first=('time','first'),
                           last=('time','last')).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df_2)
       B  first  last
0  False   0.10  0.10
1   True   0.15  0.22
2  False   0.25  0.30
3   True   0.40  0.40
4  False   0.50  0.50
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer I would not be able to solve this on my own. The idea with the help Series gave me a lot new input regarding to the use of Pandas.